# Laravel Eloquent ID as array key

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, relationship

In my controller class I am fetching all the restaurant specials, which belong to the currently logged in user, together with the cuisine type of the special as well as the restaurant to which the special belongs to.

I use the following snippet:

```
public function edit(Special $special)
{
   dd($special->with('restaurants')->with('cuisines')->get()->keyBy('id')->toArray());
}
```

This produces:

[image]

The **->keyBy('id')** method allows me to set the "Special" array key as the record ID in the database.

However, I cannot figure out how to set the relationship record array keys to their respective IDs.

For eg.
The first item in the restaurants array should have a key of "1". The first item in the cuisines array should have a key of "25".

I've tried something like this:

```
$special->with('restaurants')->keyBy('id')->with('cuisines')->keyBy('id')->get()->keyBy('id')->toArray()
```

which throws:
**Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::keyBy does not exist.**

Both my cuisines and restaurants table have a Primary Key id column.

Comment: [`keyBy(...)`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-keyby) is collection function so you need to "chain" this calls on each of your relationships. I am not going to write whole chain here but the idea is `$special->with(['restaurants', 'cuisines'])->get()->keyBy('id')->first()->restaurants->keyBy('id')`... Key point is that this will work only for **first** `$special` so you need to use [`transform()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-transform) or [`map()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-map).

Comment: Can you please give feedback on the answers?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$result = $special->with(['restaurants', 'cuisines'])->get()->keyBy('id')->map(function ($item) {
    $item->restaurants->keyBy('id');
    $item->cuisines->keyBy('id');

    return $item;
});
```

Or slightly better version:

```
$result = $special->with(['restaurants', 'cuisines'])->get()->keyBy('id')->map(function ($item) {
    foreach (array_keys($item->getRelations()) as $relation) {
        if ($item->relationLoaded($relation)) {
            $item->$relation->keyBy('id');
        }
    }

    return $item;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$special->with($relations = ['restaurants', 'cuisines'])->get()->keyBy('id')
    ->each(function($special) use($relations) {
        foreach($relations as $relation) {
            $special->setRelation($relation, $special->$relation->keyBy('id'));        
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 $result = $special->with(['restaurants', 'cuisines'])->get()
        ->keyBy('id')
        ->map(function ($item) {
        $item->restaurants->keyBy('id');
        $item->cuisines->keyBy('id');
        return $item;
    });
```

Comment: @kyslik almost there .

Comment: Yea I am there :)

Comment: You need to return $item